# Save the exact value of 1/3

Tags: python, floating-point, binary, computer-science, floating

How to save the exact value 1/3?
For example in python:

```
x = float(1/3)
print (f"{x:.50f}")
```

Result:

```
0.33333333333333331482961625624739099293947219848633
```

But I want:

```
0.333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333...
```

Comment: how many digits of `0.33333...` are you going to print?

Comment: the `decimal` module allows you to get arbitrarily close, but it's never going to be exact.  you might have better luck working algebraically, e.g. via sympy which has support for [rationals](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#rational)

Comment: It seems that there is a fractions module too that may fit your needs...

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to get the exact value. That's because of floating-point imprecision: Your computer has only a limited number of bits to store a `float` in, and if the number you want cannot be expressed with a finite number of digits in binary, then all you can get is an approximation. The approximation gets better the more bits you have (and `float`s in Python are 8 bytes, i.e., 64 bits), but it will never be absolutely exact. It's the same reason why you can't express the exact value of 1/3 in decimal.